# JAXB custom namespace prefix issue

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Is there any other way to control the custom namespace prefixes using annotations other than in the package level annotation `@Xmlns`.

Can it be done at the element level?
Also is it possible to have one namespace with multiple prefixes?

Comment: I appreciate the english lesson trylimits but an answer of some sort would be better appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you want to do, actually? Why are namespace prefixes important for you?

There are no standard element-level annotations for namespace prefixes.

The options to control namespace prefixes I know are:

- [`@XmlNS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlNs.html) you already mentioned.
- Providing a custom [`NamespacePrefixMapper`](http://java.dzone.com/articles/jaxb-and-namespace-prefixes).
- Lower-level handling of XML (for instance, on the StAX, SAX or DOM level).

What I also can imagine:

- `@XmlElementRef`/`@XmlElementRefs` normally use JAXBElements which have QNames which have prefixes. Maybe this prefix will be used.
- You can have a `QName`-typed property (`xs:QName` in XSD), it also may be used to add a namespace mapping.
- Probably something in direction of `@XmlAnyElement` (containing DOM element).
- I think I also saw something in direction of `XmlAdapter` - I think there was an option somewhere for it to be `NamespacePrefixMapper`-aware. (Actually needed for namespace-aware types like `QName`).