# JaxB Name space Prefix related

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Java marshalling process assigning name spaces prefix ns2 or ns3 randomly, is there a way to see why ns2 come first and ns3 later and vice versa?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JAXB custom namespace prefix issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27282559/jaxb-custom-namespace-prefix-issue)

Answer (score 0):

Check these questions:

- [JAXB :Need Namespace Prefix to all the elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895486/jaxb-need-namespace-prefix-to-all-the-elements)
- [JAXB custom namespace prefix issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27282559/jaxb-custom-namespace-prefix-issue/27293506#27293506)

In short, use `@XmlNs` or specify a `NamespacePrefixMapper`.