# Generate custom namespace prefix with CXF/JAXB (WSDL-first)

Tags: web-services, jaxb, cxf, jaxb2, cxf-codegen-plugin

I am migrating a webservice from Weblogic to JBoss. One of the existing clients uses a parser that is sensitive to the namespace prefixes used and I'm not able to influence this. The migration has changed some of the prefixes and I need to be able to revert them.

I looked at various options, many of them coming from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27282559/jaxb-custom-namespace-prefix-issue), but none seem suitable.

I am using the `cxf-codegen-plugin` and generating my sources from a WSDL. This seems to deny me the option of adding annotations to my sources.

I also don't use Spring with CXF (since this is not a Spring app, and I'm deploying to JBoss which uses CXF natively), so I don't have the option described in the [CXF documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxb.html) of using a `jaxws:dataBinding` (or if I do have that option, I don't understand how to configure it).

I've seen at least [one code-based JAXB example](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/11/jaxb-and-namespace-prefixes.html) that sets a marshaller property, but can't see how to do that declaratively.

My JAXB invocation already involves a custom `bindings.xml` for mapping `dateTime` types (for legacy reasons associated with the existing code) and I was expecting that something along the same lines would be possible, but I haven't been able to unearth it.

Does anyone have an idea of how this can be done, given these limitations?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this http://cxf.apache.org/docs/transformationfeature.html?

Comment: SOAP or REST webservices?

Comment: @KarthikPrasad yes, that might be an option, but JBoss doesn't give me access to the Spring properties as far as I can tell: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/JBWS/Apache+CXF+integration

Comment: @ulab SOAP webservices

Comment: You don't need spring to configure the above.

Comment: @KarthikPrasad, yes, I believe that's true. The thing is, I can't find out how to do it without Spring but declaratively (i.e. without writing code to set the JAXB marshaller property).

Answer (score 1):

Use [SOAPHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/ws/handler/soap/SOAPHandler.html) and specify as `handlerchain` in the webservice.

```
@HandlerChain(file="/handler-chain.xml")
public class WebserviceImpl {
```

**handler-chain.xml** (inside `WEB-INF/classes`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<handler-chains xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
    <handler-chain>
        <handler>
            <handler-name>NamespacePrefixHandler</handler-name>
            <handler-class>com.my.package.CustomHandler</handler-class>
        </handler>
    </handler-chain>
</handler-chains>
```

Implement `handleMessage()` to get soapenvelope and set the prefix as you want.

```
final SOAPMessage soapMessage = context.getMessage();
final SOAPEnvelope soapEnvelope = soapMessage.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
final SOAPBody soapBody = soapMessage.getSOAPBody();

soapEnvelope.setPrefix("my");
soapEnvelope.removeNamespaceDeclaration("soap");

removeNSprefix(soapBody.getChildElements());
soapBody.setPrefix("my");
```